# Android In-App Billing Public Key Exception

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I am currently playing around with in-app billing by using the Android sample code. However, I get a pretty strange error when running the sample app:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.ClassCastException:    
    com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERApplicationSpecific cannot be cast to     
    com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence
```

The application expects the public key from the Android page to be encoded in base64. I did that using a web application encoding the public key to base64 and afterwards also checked whether the encoding really worked. Byte by byte comparison showed that the content was equal.

Has anyone of you had that issue before and can give me a hint what this exception message above means?

Thank you very much,
Matthias

Comment: Post the full stack trace and the code that caused it. The key in the Market console is already Base64 encoded, so you don't need to encode it again, just paste it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid enough, this was the reason. I tried to re-encode the already encoded public key. That's why the exception came up.
Thanks!

Comment: how did u encode the public key to base64. what did u use?